# Azure cloud shell always shows "command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, azure, azure-cloud-shell

Azure cloud shell shows "command not found" no matter what command I enter - sudo, bash, az, apt-get etc.
I suppose this is due to the fact I have run these commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock

sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Is there a way to restore the cloud shell or only Azure staff has this permissions?

Comment: Strange why downvoted with "This question does not show effort in reserch". If somebody tries to search answer to the above in SO or Google I don't believe he will succeed more then I did. For me, it was stupid to describe my effort like "I googled it and nothing came out and the Azure stuff on tweeter did not help me". In this exactly case, there is no too much what else could have been done. I fill like some haters just search what to downvote here, with no explanation of course, and with now even attempt to answer the question of the post itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Shell offers a browser-accessible, **pre-configured** shell experience for managing Azure resources without the overhead of installing, versioning, and maintaining a machine yourself.

Here us the [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/features#tools) in cloud shell, please refer to it.

> Is there a way to restore the cloud shell or only Azure staff has this
>   permissions?

In cloud shell, it seems we have no permission to do some configure.

Maybe we can delete this cloud shell(in resource group), then re-install it.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. This did the work, now everything is working.
In the All Resourses screen, I have deleted the cloud-shell-storage, then just run a new Cloud Shell Console and followed the steps on the screen, allowing to create a new cloud-shell-storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start afresh with brand new storage at least, you can unmount the fileshare whilst in the shell using `clouddrive unmount`. Warnings are shown describing what will happen.

[image: clouddrive unmount warnings]

When you next try to use the shell, it will prompt you to provide a resource group, storage account and fileshare (select "show advanced settings") just as it did when configuring for the first time.

For further details see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage